# Modifying URLs with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using the following to scrape - the code works and pulls everything I intend it to - nothing complex.

The original site uses relative URLs, so the scraped html does not work.

How to I modify this so that I add http://wales.gov.uk/ to the front of each URL?

(I dont want to use  as I am likely to want to incorporate multiple scrapes on one page)

I just can't figure out the documentation.

Cheers

```
<?php

// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$html_code="http://wales.gov.uk/consultations/education/?status=open&lang=en";

// echo $html_code;

$html = file_get_html($html_code);


// Loop through all divs with class=.topic-item"
foreach($html->find('.topic-item') as $e){

echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
}


// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);

?>
```

For what it's worth, the output is at: http://h100g.org.uk/news/news4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
foreach($html->find('.topic-item') as $e){
    $e->href = 'http://wales.gov.uk/'.$e->href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - seems clear enough.

But it doesn't work for me:

    // Loop through all divs with class=.topic-item"
    foreach($html->find('.topic-item') as $e){
 
    $e->href = 'http://wales.gov.uk/'.$e->href;
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
 
    }

The html is still relative with the new http://wales.gov.uk not added.

I know I'm missing the point.

;-(

Comment: Got that:  $e->href = 'http:// wales.gov.uk/'. $e->href;

Still no joy - it seems to be ignoring the pre-pend ;-(  (I added an extra space here to make the http:// show up)

Comment: You might be using the wrong selector find('.topic-item'), probably something like find('.topic-item a') hits the target.

Comment: OK - that's it.  Looks like I need to rethink.  Least I know what's going on now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorted - as you said, wrong selector.  Sometimes you cant see wood for trees.  many thans